# How can I recover data?

Tags: system-installation, data-recovery, partitioning

While installing Ubuntu 13.04 I selected **Replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu**.

Apparently by doing so I have lost all my data that is stored in local disk:D. Is there any way that I can recover my lost data?

Comment: Please edit your question to include more details of your hard drives and what you selected during installation. If your D drive is a second hard drive, it may still be there and you just need to know where to find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can recover your data from formatted disk using `testdisk` and `photorec`, these are good open source software that is used by thousands of user when such case arrived in Linux type system.

Here are your steps how can you restore your datas:

- Boot from live CD/DVD/USB or Ubuntu, if it is opening fine..
- Install `testdisk`:

  ```
    sudo apt-get install testdisk
  ```
- Run `testdisk` to fix your partition.
- If `testdisk` fails then you can give a try to another s/w `photorec`. Find out here [How to use Photorec step by step](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step)

If you had valuable data then you can give a try to this.. I recommend to use [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step).